# react native android local images/icons assets not rendering

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working on a project with another dev and it started happening after I cloned the master branch, all the assets are still there in my project folder under `assets/` and I can literally see them by navigating into the folder, but when I run my project (**on android only**), I cannot see any of the assets being loaded, only white backgrounds. It started happening when the other dev added some `productFlavours` for different env configurations. Below are some relevant details which I think is related to solving this issue but I cannot seem to do it...

Command I used to run my android project:- `npx react-native run-android --variant=DevDebug`

My android folder:-

[image: android]

Below is my `android/app/build.gradle` file:-

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: (findProperty('expo.jsEngine') ?: "jsc") == "hermes",
    cliPath: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/cli.js",
    hermesCommand: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('hermes-engine/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/%OS-BIN%/hermesc",
    composeSourceMapsPath: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/scripts/compose-source-maps.js",
]

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../react.gradle")
apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@sentry/react-native/package.json')"].execute().text.trim(), "../sentry.gradle")

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.myapp'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 21
        versionName "0.2.14"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()
        if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments "APP_PLATFORM=android-21",
                        "APP_STL=c++_shared",
                        "NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang",
                        "GENERATED_SRC_DIR=$buildDir/generated/source",
                        "PROJECT_BUILD_DIR=$buildDir",
                        "REACT_ANDROID_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid",
                        "REACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build",
                        "NODE_MODULES_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules"
                    cFlags "-Wall", "-Werror", "-fexceptions", "-frtti", "-DWITH_INSPECTOR=1"
                    cppFlags "-std=c++17"
                    // Make sure this target name is the same you specify inside the
                    // src/main/jni/Android.mk file for the `LOCAL_MODULE` variable.
                    targets "myapp-app_appmodules"
                }
            }
            if (!enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters (*reactNativeArchitectures())
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                path "$projectDir/src/main/jni/Android.mk"
            }
        }
        def reactAndroidProjectDir = project(':ReactAndroid').projectDir
        def packageReactNdkDebugLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkDebugLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkDebugLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        def packageReactNdkReleaseLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkReleaseLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkReleaseLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        afterEvaluate {
            preDebugBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkDebugLibs)
            preReleaseBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkReleaseLibs)

            configureNdkBuildRelease.dependsOn(preReleaseBuild)
            configureNdkBuildDebug.dependsOn(preDebugBuild)
            reactNativeArchitectures().each { architecture ->
                tasks.findByName("configureNdkBuildDebug[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preDebugBuild")
                }
                tasks.findByName("configureNdkBuildRelease[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preReleaseBuild")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "env"
    productFlavors {
        production {
            dimension "env"
            applicationId 'com.myapp'
        }
        development {
            dimension "env"
            applicationId 'com.myapp'
        }
        staging {
            dimension "env"
            applicationId 'com.myapp'
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}
```

It would really help if someone could provide any solution to this problem, happy to provide any more info if needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can run below command

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Or

add below code package.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "react-native-fix-image",
}
```

and then run the commant

> npm run postinstall

Comment: Didn't work, I tried your 1st solution.

Comment: can you please try again first command I have changed and Let me know if it is not work.

Comment: same result... white backgrounds...